# How to extract month, year and date from Date level in MDX

Tags: mdx, pentaho, mdx-query

It is my first time working with MDX in JPivot, I have a Date level (Format: YYYY-MM-dd) and I have to do some queries based on the year or month of this date. I did not find a way to extract this separately.

This is my query :

```
select 
[Person].[job].Members ON COLUMNS, 
[WorkDate].[Date].Members ON ROWS 
from [Work];
```

Is there a way to do it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If the `[Workdate]` hierarchy has Year and Month levels, you can access those by using

```
[Workdate].CurrentMember.Parent.Parent.Name
```

(assuming Year is the grand-parent level of Date)

or

```
Ancestor( [Workdate].CurrentMember, [Workdate].[Year]).Name
```

If you don't have a Year/Month/Date hierarchy then you'll need to break the date string into bits using `[Workdate].CurrentMember.Name` and string functions.

Comment: Thank you the first solution worked for me I just did : [Workdate].[Year].Members